# Deferred Annuities

Tags: finance

A debt of 8000 is to be amortized  by equal monthly payments starting at the end of one year and ending at the end of 2 years if money is worth 9% every month, find each payment.

So I was thinking this is a deferred annuity but instead of find the future value we are finding the annuity.

Plugging in my equation
n+d = 2 years which is 24 payments
Future value = 8000
 AM i doing it right?

$Annuity$ = $\frac{8000}{\frac{1+\left(\frac{0.09}{12}\right)^{24}}{\frac{0.09}{12}}-{\frac{1+\left(\frac{0.09}{12}\right)^{12}}{\frac{0.09}{12}}}}$

Comment: You want $\left(1+{.09\over12}\right)^{24}$ for example.  You've got the left parentheses in the wrong place.

Comment: Are you still interested in an answer?

Answer (score 0):

$i=0.09/12$, $v=\frac{1}{1 +i} $, $L=8000$

$$
A=\frac{L}{v^{12}\times\frac{1-v^{12}}{i}  } 
$$